# Codeigniter adding data to database and then process it

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to built a type of online shop.
I want to create a process order function in order to verify the details of the order the clients puts in.

I am stuck though because on the last page i have the data to submit and when i click i go to main/process_order where i insert the data in the table and then use curl to comunicate with another server.

My question is: when i hit submit and then stop on the process_order page if i reload it 1000 times, the table will be filled with the same 1000 lines, so this can be a security issue. Also if i make a function to add the data to db and then redirect to process_order it will be another issue because i still need my data that was posted.

What's the best way to solve this. I hope i made it as clear as i can.
Code:

```
$data=array(        
        'userid' => $userid,
        'email' => $email_data,   
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'discount' => $this->input->post('discount'),       
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'final_price' => $this->input->post('final_price'),
        'client_data' => $this->input->post('client_info'),
        'client_ip' => $this->input->post('client_ip'),
        'time' => $date
        );

    $this->db->insert('orders_temp', $data);
```

Comment: Check if same data exits once you save it to db.

Comment: After the data is saved to db, the page is still loading for about 2-3 seconds when anyone can stop it and reload it. So it can fill up the table with same entries.

Comment: that's i'm saying once table have entry you can check if record exits no need to insert it again. it doesn't matter then it get refresh.

Comment: @Rorschach i check by ip. if the main details are the same (quantity price item etc.) i will not write again the order. If there is any difference for the same ip i will overwrite the order. If there is not any other order for that ip i will add one. Is this enough ?

Comment: Ok, great, i hope it's ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help. Do a check on the userid and the time before you insert the data. You would need make sure to do a search on database fields that are unique (unless the time field is the full time)

```
$data=array(        
    'userid' => $userid,
    'email' => $email_data,   
    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
    'discount' => $this->input->post('discount'),       
    'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
    'final_price' => $this->input->post('final_price'),
    'client_data' => $this->input->post('client_info'),
    'client_ip' => $this->input->post('client_ip'),
    'time' => $date
 );

if (<!--CONDITIONAL STATEMENT-->)
{
    $this->db->insert('orders_temp', $data); 
}
```

Comment: I permit to users that are not logged in to buy so this can't be done. Also the time is full time, anyway if it was only the day month year wasn't good enaugh if he wanted to order anything else he would have only the initial order.

Comment: @AlexMuntean you can change the `get_where` to be whatever fields you want to check on, or whatever conditions. But essentially, you need to do a check on some unique combination of data before you insert the record in the table.

Comment: yes Donovan you are right, i am already doing this but not with get_Where, i'm doing it with if statemtent. Anyway this may get handy in order to shrink the code. Thanks

Comment: Good deal. Glad you got it sorted out @AlexMuntean. If this answer helped you, can you vote it up or mark it correct? If not, can you post your own answer and mark it correct? Thanks.